# How do I set the autoverify attribute in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is my Xamarin code:

```
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", Label = "MyappName", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
DataScheme = "http",
DataHost = "www.mywebsite.net",
Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
```

---

Here is the [Android documentation about app links](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/app-linking.html).

As you can see, I added an intent filter and set a datascheme, a datahost etc. However, the Android documentation also describes the autoverify attribute. How do I set this in my Xamarin project?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation link that you have provided, AutoVerify is a property that has been introduced in Android M Preview now. As per Xamarin's page their latest release only is till API 22. You can check for releases in this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/). Once they have M Developer Preview really, ensure you have grabbed all the latest versions and try again.